# strtok doesn't work with non-const char argument

Tags: c, strtok, char-pointer

I have this function that take a sentence and reverse each words.
I have to modify the value in-place and the return value should be Null. 
I can't modify the main:

```
int main()
{
    char *string= "hello";
    reverser(string);
    printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

In my `reverser` function i use `strtok` which require a `non-const char*`

```
char* reverser(char *sentence) {
    char *copy = strdup(sentence);
    char *string;
    int i, j;

    for(j = 0; (string = strtok(j ? NULL : copy, " ")) != NULL; j++)
        for(i = strlen(string) - 1; i >= 0; --i, j++)
            sentence[j] = string[i];
    return NULL;
}
```

Even using strdup it doesn't work and I can't figure out why...
Someone has any suggestion to make it work?
thank you

Comment: Did you know that `strdup` already copies `sentence`'s contents into the `copy`'s buffer?

Comment: Sentence is pointing to a string literal. It shall not be modified.

Comment: By the way, you're returning always `NULL` from `reserver`. Not even looked at your for loop, but these should already be a few bugs that you should fix.

Comment: Indeed, return the string that was `strdup`ed. Then you would have `printf("%s\n", reverser(string));` BTW did you read the man page for `strdup`? You already made a copy before you use `strcpy` to do the same thing. Moreover your implementaion of `strtok` is ugly and hard to follow. The idiomatic way is to use a `while` loop based on the pointer returned by `strtok`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to delete the strcpy... I just edited it. Btw the behavior and the question are the same

Comment: well, beauty is subjective

Comment: "strtok doesn't work with non-const char argument" --> `strtok()` is working fine. Attempting to modify `"hello"` is not OK.  Try `char string[] = "hello";` and free your allocated data when done with it.

Comment: If you can't modify that main code, your task is impossible (without cheating).

Comment: @melpomene I second that statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `char *string= "hello";` with `char string[] = "hello";`

Otherwise `string` will be unmodifiable, and it would be **impossible** for the reverser function to work. (given that it will always return NULL)